# Complementary subspaces ($K$ and $L$) problem, where $K=\ker(p)$ and $L=\ker(q)$ with $p,q: U \rightarrow U$ linear maps.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am struggling with solving the following question:

> Let $U$ be a vector space over field $F$ and $p,q: U \rightarrow U$ linear maps. Assume $p+q=id_U$ and $pq=0$. Let $K=\ker(p)$ and $L=\ker(q)$. Prove that :
>
> (i) $qp=0$
>
> (ii) $K$ and $L$ are complementary in $U$.
>
> (iii) Give an example of the above situation when $p$ and $q$ are both non-zero.

What I have already shown is that $K=\operatorname{im}(q)$ and $p=p^2$. I also know that complementary subspaces are such that they are disjoint and $K+L=U$. Has anyone got any suggestions how to proceed from this point?

(this is not a duplicate)

Comment: Guys, please help me, you are my last resort :-)

Comment: Complimentary subspaces are **not** disjoint. Rather, they contain exactly one common element.

Comment: Yeah, zero vector, but this is common for every space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove $p^2=p$ and $qp=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406235/prove-p2-p-and-qp-0)

Comment: As for examples, do you know any transformations $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ with a non-trivial image and a non-trivial kernel? That's a good place to start.

Comment: Another thing to consider: what is $\ker(q)\cap\operatorname{im}(q)$ for a linear transformation $q:U\to U$?

Comment: How come is that a duplicate? I have already shown these 2 propositions that are given in the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

First note that question 3 is the easiest: the identity transformation is usually written as a matrix which has zeroes everywhere except for the diagonal where it has 1's; an easy way to find matrices (which we hope will be representing maps p and q) that add up to this matrix is to take a matrix who has 1's only in the first (say) $k$ entries of the diagonal (and zero's everywhere else) and a matrix which has 1's only on the last $n-k$ entries of the diagonals where $n = \dim U$. Of course it seems unlikely that the first and simplest guess of what $p$ and $q$ could be already works, but HEYO! it does!

Now having an example, it easier to understand geometrically what kind of situation we are talking about here. (Not worrying for the moment about whether we can *prove* that we are in this situation.) We have complementary subspaces K and L which means that every element $u$ of $U$ can be written in precisely one way as $u = k + l$ with $k \in K$ and $l \in L$ (*existence* of this decomposition is exactly your statment that $K + L = U$ and *uniqueness* is $K \cap L =\{0\}$). The maps $p$ and $q$ are the maps that send $u$ to $l$ and $k$ respectively. Hence $p$ is the *projection* of $U$ onto $L$ (along the decomposition) and $q$ the projection onto $K$. Your result that $p^2 = p$ is a fancy way of saying that $p$ behaves like how you picture a projection geometrically: it maps arbitrary elements of $U$ to $\im(p) = L$ but leaves elements of $L$ exactly where they are.

Ok now for the proof. From the above we see three things:

a) the roles of p and q, K and L etc should be interchangeble. So for everything you know (qp = 0, K = im(q), p^2 = 0) we should be able to prove the mirror image: pq = 0, L = im(p), q^2 = 0. (I get to the 'how' below).

b) Once we have K = im(q) and L = im(p) the statement U = K + L is immediate from an equation that we already saw: $u = p(u) + q(u)$ for every $u$. Note that this last equation is just $p + q = id$ in disguise.

c) We should be able to show that $p$ maps elements of $L$ to themselves and $q$ maps elements of $K$ to themselves. Any element in $K \cap L$ is hence mapped to itself by both $pq$ and $qp$. This solves the question about what is $K \cap L$ provided that we *can* show the things in the first sentence of c). Similarly y to what I said above $L= im(p)$ and $p^2 = p$ show the first of these two.  (And you can guess how to do the second).

So... It all boils down to proving a).

To see the symmetry between p and q a bit better I feel it really helps to write the identiy transformation on $U$ as 1 rather than $\id_U$. (After all it is the 1-element in the ring of linear transformations of $U$.) So we have $p$ and we have $q = 1 - p$. Writing $1-p$ instead of $q$ makes it clear that $p$ and $q$ commute: $p(1-p) = (1-p)p$ obviously, so if one of the two equals zero, so does the other. This gives you the first desired equation in a), I leave the rest to you.